# BitBucket -- Reviewing manual changes in a merge commit

Tags: git, bitbucket

BitBucket has a [nice Pull Request (PR) process](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/pull-requests-and-code-review-223220593.html) for reviewing code changes associated with a commit. But sometimes we find ourselves in a situation where we have two long-lived branches, e.g. "develop" and "future_release" that can diverge quite a bit. When the time comes to merge future_release into develop, it takes some manual effort to reconcile issues due to the divergence of these branches.

Assume all code changes prior to the merge in both "develop" and "future_release" have already gone through peer review and don't need to be reviewed again.

Is there any good way, using BitBucket Pull Requests UI or otherwise, to specifically review the manual code changes that were made as part of the merge itself to resolve conflicts and maybe other discrepancies?

Comment: Just to clarify, you just want to see what changes were made in a merge commit as part of resolving merge conflicts? Maybe update your title to be more specific about that?

Comment: @jnrbsn Thanks for the suggestion. Updated title.

Comment: You could maybe make a new branch from the one you wish to merge, do the merge commit on that branch, then make a PR from that new branch into the one you wish to merge? The diff should be just what you're looking for (though you'll end up with another commit that you'll have to squash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitbucket does not currently have a way to see what changes were made in a merge commit as part of resolving merge conflicts. However, this is not too difficult to do in the command line.

Think of it this way: Someone tried to do a merge, and they were left in an "unmerged" state because of the conflicts. They made some changes to resolve the conflicts, committed those changes, and then they were left with a new merge commit as the result. If you know this merge commit, then you know the two things they were trying to merge (because they're the parent commits of the merge commit). So you can put yourself into that same unmerged state that they were in, and then do a diff between that state and their resultant merge commit.

Here's a bash script that does exactly that for you:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Pass the merge commit as the only argument to the script
COMMIT="$1"
# Create a temporary directory where we'll use a copy of the repo
TMP_REPO="$(mktemp -d)"

# Clone the original repo into the temporary directory, and setup the
# original repo as an "alternate" using --shared
git clone --quiet --shared . "${TMP_REPO}"
cd "${TMP_REPO}"

# Checkout the first parent of the merge commit (this is the "destination"
# commit of the merge)
git checkout --quiet "${COMMIT}^1"
# Merge the second parent (the "source" of the merge) of the merge
# commit into the first, creating "unmerged" state with conflicts
printf "GIT MERGE OUTPUT:\n\n"
git merge --quiet --no-commit "${COMMIT}^2"
# Stage everything in the working tree, including all unresolved conflicts
git add .
# Commit the changes
git commit --quiet --message "Commit all merge conflicts"

printf "\n==================================================\n\n"

# Do a diff between the commit you just created and the original merge commit
git diff --find-renames "HEAD..${COMMIT}"

rm -rf "${TMP_REPO}"
```

Run it from inside your git repo passing the merge commit hash as the only argument, like this:

```
$ /path/to/script.sh d29ce0c1420b18c7e8f1ce2bf3667f6609bf215d
GIT MERGE OUTPUT:

Auto-merging numbers.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in numbers.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

==================================================

diff --git a/numbers.txt b/numbers.txt
index 18ac646..a4ab7d4 100644
--- a/numbers.txt
+++ b/numbers.txt
@@ -1,9 +1,4 @@
-<<<<<<< HEAD
+two
 four
-five
 six
-=======
-seven
 eight
-nine
->>>>>>> d29ce0c1420b18c7e8f1ce2bf3667f6609bf215d^2
```